# Environment variables and git

Tags: git, environment-variables

I'm trying to drop out the UI of git and to use the command line instead.
I have simple question.

I have downloaded the git and the binary file (git.exe) is stored under D:\Program Files\Git\bin

My question is if I want to use the command `git clone` but I don't want every time to go to the previews file to use this command how can I make it?

As I know I have to put the path to Environment Variables but I don't know where(under system variables or user variables) and how.

I will appreciate it if someone could guide me a bit.

Thank you and BR

Comment: install git bash for windows. It will set all env variables for u

Comment: Kindly watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDR433b0HJY

Comment: And search what is Source Code Version Control?

Answer (score 0):

**[Download](https://git-scm.com/download/win)** and install git.

Now add [aliases](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for your common commands.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

---

#### Setting the commit alias

```
#set the alias
git config --global alias.cm "commit -m"
```

#### Using it:

```
git cm "message"
```